# D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, string, bitmap

I received this error. I did not know why it was. I thought it was because of truncated input or null input. I checked everything but finally resolved by changing method

> D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

I used this code to convert string to bitmap

```
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String getContent) {
        try {
            byte[] encodeByte = getContent.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK FOR ME. Finally found solution myself. Posting for others with same error/exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by using this method

```
    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try {
            byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```